# Pack identical rectangles in a circle

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

I have identical rectangles of size *(w, h)*. I would like to calculate the maximum number of such rectangles that I can pack (no overlap) in a circle of radius *r*. All the rectangles should also have the same orientation.

If $h = w$, I found $N=\pi(r-w)^2/w^2$.

Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for an upper bound. But I couldn't find a formula even for the square case, so I was putting an approximation.

Comment: Related : [Is there an algorithm out there that will show you how to fit the most rectangles into a circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6713)

Comment: There is no formula even for squares. The best you can expect is a table such as provided by [Erich Friedman](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/squincir/). A separate table would be required for each value of aspect ratio $a=w/h$.

Comment: More related questions : [Number of Squares in a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/606002), [Mathematica SE :  packing squares into a circle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30625/), [How many squares fit in a circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3007527), [Fitting a grid inside a circle, is the solution always symmetric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/973100),

Comment: For the unit square case $(h=w=1)$ you can use curve fitting to find an approximate formula from the 35 data points in Erich Friedman's website. The power law $r=an^b$ is a very good fit with $a=0.7682, b=0.44189$ and $R^2=0.996683$. Here $n$ is the number of unit squares and $r$ is the radius of the smallest circle they can be fitted into.

Comment: Did you try an approach that scales it by setting a procedure of packing n element and based on that calculate the radius?

Comment: Is orientation limited?